# Why does mount show tons of bind mount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I did in my ubuntu system

```
mount -bind /a/tmp /tmp
```

but after some days, if 'mount' shows tons of the bind mounts like the following

```
...
/dev/sda on /a/tmp ...
/dev/sda on /tmp ...
/dev/sda on /a/tmp ...
/dev/sda on /tmp ...
/dev/sda on /a/tmp ...
/dev/sda on /tmp ...
/dev/sda on /a/tmp ...
/dev/sda on /tmp ...
/dev/sda on /a/tmp ...
/dev/sda on /tmp ...
```

The total number of lines is like 65,536, which is 2^16. It seems it reaches the limit of that mount can show...

Buf if I check /etc/fstab, we get only

```
 /a/tmp /tmp auto defaults,nofail,bind 0 2
 /dev/sda /mnt auto defaults,nofail 0 2
```

How could this happen...?

Comment: I found a log https://blog.dhampir.no/content/duplicate-bind-mounts-with-chroots-on-systemd which says this can be related to mount information propagation.

However in my case I did not add more mount under /a/tmp and /tmp. Not sure how this can cause the issue.

Comment: Is `/a` an auto-mounter?